# A space is needed to let line_terminator be recognized

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, lex, lexical-analysis

In my `lexer.mll` I have declared `EOS` as follows:

```
let line_feed = '\n' (* %x200A *)
let carriage_return = '\r' (* %x200D *)
let line_terminator = line_feed | carriage_return | carriage_return line_feed 
(* KO: %x2028 | %x2029 *)
let LINE_END = line_terminator

let tab_character = '\x09' (* CHARACTER TABULATION *)
let eom_character = '\x19' (* END OF MEDIUM *)
let space_character = '\x20' (* SPACE *)
let underscore = '\x5F' (* LOW LINE or SPACING UNDERSCORE *)

let WSC = tab_character | eom_character | space_character 
let line_continuation = WSC* underscore WSC* line_terminator
let WS = (WSC | line_continuation)+
let EOL = WS? LINE_END
let EOS = EOL*

rule token = parse
  | WS       { token lexbuf }
  | LINE_END { newline lexbuf; token lexbuf }
  | EOS      { EOS }
```

In my `parser.mly`, I have something like this:

```
%token EOS
...
%%
nonterminal :
    statement EOS 
    statement { semantic-action }
```

I edit my `test_KO.txt` under `Emacs` as follows, it raises an error while parsing:

```
a_statement
b_statement
```

However, if I add one `space` after `a_statement` as follows, it passes the parsing:

```
a_statement(space)
b_statement
```

I guess the reason is `line_terminator` cannot be recognized for `test_KO.txt`, though `a_statemnt` and `b_statement` are not in the same line; `line_terminator` can be recognized if there is one `space` between them.

Do you think adding [x2028](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) and [x2029](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm) to `line_terminator` would solve the problem? As `ocamllex` probably does not support well unicode, it would be complicated to test it...

Otherwise, is there any other solution for the problem?

Comment: Did you get your problem solved? What are the parsing rules for a_statement and b_statement? There are plenty of possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your WS, LINE_END and EOS rules can all try to match the same string, see [the OCamllex manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual026.html#htoc144) for the 'longest match' rule that is used to select which regex actually matches.

When you just have a single line terminator between the statements both the 'LINE_END' and 'EOS' rule match only 1 character, but the 'LINE_END' rule occurs earlier so it is selected. No EOS token is emitted, and you get an error from your grammar.

When you have both a space and a line terminator the rule for 'WS' would match 1 character,
and the rule for EOS would match two (both the space and newline), so the rule for EOS is selected. An EOS token is emitted now and your grammar works as expected.

Easiest would be probably to remove the EOS token from your lexer and grammar.